# QML Fontloader use Google fonts

Tags: qt, qml, google-font-api

I am trying to use QML FontLoader to load [Goole fonts](https://github.com/google/fonts/tree/master/apache) in QML application:

```
FontLoader {
id:webFont
source:  "https://github.com/google/fonts/raw/master/apache/cousine/Cousine-Regular.ttf"
}
```

I get following Error:

> QML FontLoader: Cannot load font:
>   "https://github.com/google/fonts/raw/master/apache/cousine/Cousine-Regular.ttf"

When I use the font source URL in browser, the font downloads successfully, which signs the link is correct.

Interestingly, I download the font manually, add as resource to Qt project, and use it in FontLoader, it works correctly ..! any clue?

Comment: In linux with Qt 5.11.1 I do not have that problem: https://imgur.com/a/U5z4JQY

Comment: @eyllanesc .. Interesting .. I  use Ubuntu 18, Qt 5.11.1

Comment: I've tried it on Arch Linux, maybe you have problems with some proxy.

Comment: @eyllanesc, Seems so .. I tested with Image source and got similar issue! Thanks.